# Is it possible to declare a variable with a value for string and a placeholder in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to initialize a long string value to a variable, but this string has a word that can not be constant, like this example.

Say I want to store a string like this.

```
str = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/7833397/meskerem"
```

But assume the  number 7833397 will change over time, so I am trying to find a way to store the string while making making a wildcard for the number. But I am not sure if this can be done in Python

Comment: you should avoid names of built-ins for your objects

Comment: Strings in python are *immutable*, i.e. they cannot be changed, they are read-only.  So there is very little point in trying to do what you say - you will have to create a new string object regardless.  You might use a list instead, `join` the elements together when you need the string.

Comment: @cdarke Not sure about this, but isn't  there a sprintf() function somewhere? I also saw something like `foobar%s % ($val)`  some time ago but not sure how to use it

Comment: @Gahan Yes, actually. I get the data in json format, but the number must change overtime

Comment: Yes there is more than one way, there is also a `format` method, but these both create a new string object, they don't alter an existing one.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I am not using built-in objects, where did you see that?

Comment: The comment about using built-in names was because you say `str =`, and `str` is a special built-in function.

Comment: @meskerem Yes, you *are* using Python built-in objects. But I believe Azat was referring to your use of the name `str`,  which shadows the built-in `str` function. You should avoid that.

Comment: @meskerem, if you need to fetch url from json then write that sample json code with 2 or 3 element and your desire result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) method.

```
template = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/{0}/meskerem"

# Lots of stuff happens here

url = template.format("7833397")
```

The `format` method supports its own little mini language, and depending on your use-case you may find it more intuitive to name the various parts of your template, too:

```
template = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/{id}/{username}"

# Lots of stuff happens here

url = template.format(id="7833397", username="meskerem")
```

Answer (score 6):

First, avoid usign the identifier `str`. Second, you can put placeholders in strings using two methods of string formatting:

#### Old style

The "old" style uses C-style string formatting syntax, and "modulo" operation on the string to do the actual insertion. You can pass multiple replacements as a tuple:

```
s = "foo%sbaz" # expects a string
print(s%"bar")
s2 = "foo%s%d"
print(s2%("bar", 2))
```

#### [New style](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

The "new" style uses a generic `{}` which can be filled using the `str.format()` method. Multiple replacements are passed as a unzipped tuple, i.e. as mutiple arguments:

```
s = "foo{}baz" # can be "anything"
print(s.format("bar"))
s2 = "foo{}{}"
print(s2.format("bar", 2))
```

[This site](https://pyformat.info/) might come handy as a reference.

Comment: A previous commenter commented about f-strings, which can be used since Python 3.6: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals

Answer (score 0):

You can use '%s'(string formatting syntax )

```
modified_str = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/%s/meskerem" % (number,)
```

Comment: alternatively `"https://stackoverflow.com/users/{}/meskerem".format(number)` or `f"https://stackoverflow.com/users/{number}/meskerem"` is also good choice

Comment: @Gahan yes, on Python 3.6 f-strings are the way to go if used thoughtfully.

Comment: Please don't perpetuate the mistake of using `str =`